# Error when creating redux store in Angular: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically

Tags: angular, typescript, compiler-errors, redux

The error appears in app.module.ts. Relevant code:

```
import { createStore, Store } from 'redux';
import { rootReducer } from './redux-store/index';

const appStore = createStore(rootReducer);

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: 'AppStore', useValue: appStore }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am using the latest Angular-cli, and this didn't happen with previous versions. The full error text is:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Only initialized variables and constants can be referenced because the value of this variable is needed by the template compiler (position 251:14 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol createStore in /home/daco/handwork/Angular2/MileageStats2/node_modules/redux/index.d.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /home/daco/handwork/Angular2/MileageStats2/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /home/daco/handwork/Angular2/MileageStats2/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /home/daco/handwork/Angular2/MileageStats2/src/app/app.module.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `useFactory` instead of `useValue`

```
export function appStoreFactory() {
 return createStore(rootReducer);
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: 'AppStore', useFactory: appStoreFactory }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```